# grep -A|grep -o

Tags: regex, grep

Hey I am trying to output the exact matching expressions that I want (and there are a series of them in an HTML page). For that in order to be able to get rid of the rubbish I need to use grep -A and then from this result match the expression that I want. However, it doe not work. What I am expecting after

```
curl -s https://somewebsite.com|grep A- 2 '<h3 class="title">'|grep -o '<a href="[a-zA-Z0-9./]+">'
```

I would expect to get:

only something like

```
<a href="/blah/blah/9/blah.">
```

but instead, I get everything back as if I did not have the second grep at all.

```
<h3 class="title">
<a href="/blah/blah/9/blah.">
</h3>
```

Could you guys help me with the problem?

Here is an edit which might help you guys to help me.
If I do the following:

```
curl -s https://somewebsite.com|grep A- 2 '<h3 class="title">' >> test.txt
grep -o '<a href="[a-zA-Z0-9./]+">' test.txt
```

everything works just fine.

Comment: Try `grep -Eo '<a href="[^"]+">'`

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work either. Is the output from grep -A or B different? Because the other combinations work. it is just this that for some reason does not work!

Comment: Also, I should note that if I save the results of the first grep command in a text file and then run the second command on the file I get the result that I need, but I do not want to waste time on saving the file and reading from a file.

Comment: No that was a typo here. I did the correct version when I was running the code. And thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it in my question.

Comment: Another update: I fixed it. There was an invisible character in my script changing everything. This works fine. I would appreciate if you remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify **metacharacters** usage in your pattern upon using `grep`. This can be done with `-E` argument:

```
$ curl -s 'https://somewebsite.com' |\
    grep -A 2 '<h3 class="title">' |\
      grep -Eo '<a href="[a-zA-Z0-9.\/]+">'

# <a href="/blah/blah/9/blah.">
```